# Missing en-UK.yml file for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm trying to switch one of my websites into en-UK so that I get the correct date and currency formats etc...

I have found this yaml file:

http://github.com/mattetti/globalite/blob/master/lang/rails/en-UK.yml

Any ideas if there is a better one to use?

I also checked here but could not see it:

http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a better solution than to keep a duplicate version of en.yml and simply change the $ to £.

There is a plugin that lets you only override the values you require:

http://github.com/javan/rails-i18n-translation-inheritance-helper

#### config/environment.rb

```
config.i18n.default_locale = 'en-UK'
```

and then create:

#### config/locales/en-UK.yml - for special cases

```
en-UK:
  number:
    currency:
      format:
        unit: '£'
        format: '%u%n'
```

#### config/locales/en.yml - for all English translations

```
en:
 btn_submit: Submit
```

This works a treat and will also mean that I don't need to maintain the file apart from any special cases like above.

#### View

```
=t 'btn_submit' #Submit
=h number_to_currency(@price, :precision => 0) #£1,000
```

Hope this helps others as it took a while to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for en-GB :)

https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-GB.yml